# Last word not reversed while reversing a sentence

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I have written i program which will reverse a sentence and print it.

In this code i get all the words correct except the last one. i.e after reversing the sentence in the code, "hiii" still remains "iiih" , rest of the output is proper.

```
void reverse(char * s, int len){
    int counter = 0;
    int end = len - 1;
    char temp;

    for (counter = 0; counter < len / 2; counter++, end--) {
        temp = s[counter];
        s[counter] = s[end];
        s[end] = temp;
    }
}

int main(void){
    char s[] = "hiii all i want to reverse this sentence so please help me fast";
    int c = 0;
    int len = strlen(s);
    int wl = 0;
    int start = 0;
    printf("\n    s =  %s", s);
    reverse(s, len);

    for (c = 0; c < len; c++){
        if (!wl)
            start = c;

        if (s[c] != ' '){
            wl++;
        }
        else {
            reverse(s + start, wl);
            wl = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("\nnow s =  %s", s);
}
```

Comment: first correct  indentation. learn [Indenting C Programs](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html).

Comment: Priyanka check this [help-center](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21348646/revisions) soon, and learn [how to ask a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last word in the string is not terminated by a space character.
Therefore you need something like this *after* the for loop (untested):

```
if (wl > 0) {
     reverse(s + start, wl);
}
```

to reverse the last word as well.

*Added:* Full code:

```
int main(void) {
    char s[] = "hiii all i want to reverse this sentence so please help me fast";
    int c = 0;
    int len = strlen(s);
    int wl = 0;
    int start = 0;
    printf("\n    s =  %s", s);
    reverse(s, len);

    for (c = 0; c < len; c++) {
        if (!wl) {
            start = c;
        }

        if (s[c] != ' ') {
            wl++;
        } else {
            reverse(s + start, wl);
            wl = 0;
        }

    }

    if (wl > 0) {
        reverse(s + start, wl);
    }

    printf("\nnow s =  %s", s);

}
```

Output:

```
    s =  hiii all i want to reverse this sentence so please help me fast
now s =  fast me help please so sentence this reverse to want i all hiii
```

Comment: i got what u said but where should i put above line in my code?

Comment: @Priyanka: After the for loop, just before the `printf("\nnow s =  %s", s);`

Comment: I think there's a problem with your answer, see mine.

Comment: @EOF: I don't think that there is a problem with my answer. I have tested it now and it works.

Comment: @EOF: Note that you could make your solution work by changing the for loop to `for (c = 0; c <= len; c++)` ...

Comment: @EOF where is your answer??

Comment: @MartinR if i put d line which u told, that giving some different answer only :(

Comment: @Priyanka: What different answer do you get? It works for me. I have added the full code and the output to my answer.

Comment: @MartinR this program is using extra space or no? because in a aptitude test paper it ws askd to "write a program to reverse a sentence without using extra space"..pls tell me abt it

Comment: @Priyanka: That *probably* means that you should not use an additional character array. Your code uses only one character array (s), so you should be fine.

Comment: @MartinR but in the function "reverse()" we are passing array as argument, so wil it not take extra space?? in the function reverse?

Comment: @Priyanka: Passing an array to a function in C just passes a *pointer* to the array (a pointer to the first element, to be precise).

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the wonderful explanation. it cleared my doubt :)